# Wifi no longer working, cannot start dhcpcd@wlan0

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dhcp, dhcpcd, iwd

After the last update on my archlinux install, the wifi is no longer working.
I check the packages updated and the package **iwd** got updated.

When I try to connect to my modem in wifi using `iwctl`, I get an "Operation failed" after entering the passphrase.

I checked that NetworkManager.service is stopped and disabled.

When I run `ip addr`, I see that there is no ip address on my wlan0 interface.

Here is status of some of the daemons, and the command I use :

`systemctl status wpa_supplicant.service` shows that is ACTIVE

`systemctl status dhcpcd.service` ACTIVE

`systemctl status iwd.service` ACTIVE with some error messages

`systemctl status dhcpcd@wlan0` FAILED

When I run `sudo systemctl start dhcpcd@wlan0`, I get this error message :

`Job for dhcpcd@wlan0.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration. See "systemctl status dhcpcd@wlan0.service" and "journalctl -xeu dhcpcd@wlan0.service" for details.`

What should I be checking next and what could be the cause of `dhcpcd@wlan0` failing ?

**EDIT :**

Here is the output of `systemctl status iwd.service` :

```
● iwd.service - Wireless service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iwd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-02-10 22:34:21 CET; 5min ago
   Main PID: 336 (iwd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6926)
     Memory: 2.6M
        CPU: 200ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/iwd.service
             └─336 /usr/lib/iwd/iwd

Feb 10 22:34:21 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:22 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:22 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:22 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:22 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:22 archlinux iwd[336]: Could not register frame watch type 00d0: -95
Feb 10 22:34:23 archlinux iwd[336]: CMD_SET_CQM failed: Operation not supported
Feb 10 22:34:28 archlinux iwd[336]: 4-Way handshake failed for ifindex: 3, reason: 15
Feb 10 22:35:42 archlinux iwd[336]: CMD_SET_CQM failed: Operation not supported
Feb 10 22:35:47 archlinux iwd[336]: 4-Way handshake failed for ifindex: 3, reason: 15
```

**EDIT 2:**

It may also be related that, when running `pacman -Syu`, I get a bunch of warnings of the type `Possibly missing firmware for module:`. But not of those are the `b43` broadcom firmware used by laptop's wireless card. I think. I don't know how to make reappear those warnings.

Comment: Please update your question with the error messages from `iwd.service`.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am experiencing the same issues.

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch Yes my problem got resolved. Maybe that's because of a new update. So I don't know what was the problem. One thing I've noticed is that sometimes, I need to "force" a connection (opening Chrome and loading youtube.com, say). It looks like it is required sometimes to initialize things.